# how to convert an int from user input into a list?

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, integer

I am a newbie in Python. I want to know how to convert input from user into a list. I tried this code but the result is an error...

```
a = int(input('Masukkan angka pertama : '))
b = int(input('Masukkan angka kedua : '))
c = int(input('Masukkan angka ketiga : '))

if a < b < c :
    print (list(a, b, c))
```

Comment: What does the if condition signify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
print([a,b,c])
```

The `list()` function works when you wish to convert another sequence(eg string, tuple etc.) into a list.

Comment: thankyou so much brother, this is more simple and i think it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
list1 = []#Creating empty list
a = int(input('Masukkan angka pertama : '))
b = int(input('Masukkan angka kedua : '))
c = int(input('Masukkan angka ketiga : '))
list1.append(a)#Adding user input to list
list1.append(b)
list1.append(c)
print(list1)#Printing list
```

You can learn more about lists.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/

Comment: That is pretty unnecessary when you can directly use lst = [a, b, c].

Comment: @MNizar you can click on tick if you think it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

list() accepts an iterable and while you are passing integers. So the last line should be

```
print(list[a, b, c])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is nearly good.
Problem is that list() expects only one parameter which must be an iterable.
So you can use a tuple or a list(strange but why not)

```py
print(list((a, b, c))) 
print(list([a, b, c]))
```

You can also avoid to use list() function

```py
print([a, b, c])
```

And you can use append as suggested by @Abhyuday Vaish